# Flattening an XML document

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I am currently trying to flatten a deep-structured XML document in C# so that every value of an element is converted to an attibute.

The XML structure is as follows:

```
<members>
    <member xmlns="mynamespace" id="1" status="1">
        <sensitiveData>
            <notes/>
            <url>someurl</url>
            <altUrl/>
            <date1>somedate</date1>
            <date2>someotherdate</date2>
            <description>some description</description>
            <tags/>
            <category>some category</category>
        </sensitiveData>
        <contacts>
            <contact contactId="1">
                <contactPerson>some contact person</contactPerson>
                <phone/>
                <mobile>mobile number</mobile>
                <email>some@email.com</email>
            </contact>
        </contacts>
    </member>
</members>
```

What I want it to look like is this:

```
<members>
    <member xmlns="mynamespace" id="1" status="1" notes="" url="someurl" altUrl="" date1="somedate" date2="someotherdate" description="some description" tags="" category="some category" contactId="1" contactPerson="some contact person" phone="" mobile="mobile number" email="some@email.com" />
</members>
```

I could just parse away on the element names and their attributes, but since this XML comes from a webservice that I can't control, I have to create some sort of dynamic parser to flatten this as the structure *can* change at some point.

Should be worth noting that the XML structure comes as an XElement from the webservice.

Has anyone tried to do this before and would be helpful to share how? :-) It would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks a lot in advance.

All the best,

Bo

Comment: the XML you show is invalid ( `/kontakter` has no opening tag?)... as to your question there is no general answer since it all depends on the rules you want to apply (for example what should happen if there is more than one `contact` etc.). My question is: WHY do you want to "flatten" this XML ?

Comment: Hi Yahia, thanks - that was just a typo :) I need to flatten this to be able to import it into a CMS.

Comment: then IMHO XSLT is the way to go as it allows to change the transformation rules even after deployment...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(@"<members>...</members>");

var result = new XDocument(
    new XElement(doc.Root.Name,
        from x in doc.Root.Elements()
        select new XElement(x.Name,
            from y in x.Descendants()
            where !y.HasElements
            select new XAttribute(y.Name.LocalName, y.Value))));
```

*Result:*

```xml
<members>
  <member notes="" url="someurl" altUrl="" date1="somedate" date2="someotherdate" description="some description" tags="" category="some category" contactPerson="some contact person" phone="" mobile="mobile number" email="some@email.com" xmlns="mynamespace" />
</members>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use this XSLT 1.0 stylesheet. You might want to modify how it handles multiple `<contact>` elements.

**Input XML**

```
<members>
  <member xmlns="mynamespace" id="1" status="1">
    <sensitiveData>
      <notes/>
      <url>someurl</url>
      <altUrl/>
      <date1>somedate</date1>
      <date2>someotherdate</date2>
      <description>some description</description>
      <tags/>
      <category>some category</category>
    </sensitiveData>
    <contacts>
      <contact contactId="1">
        <contactPerson>some contact person</contactPerson>
        <phone/>
        <mobile>mobile number</mobile>
        <email>some@email.com</email>
      </contact>
      <contact contactId="2">
        <contactPerson>second contact person</contactPerson>
        <phone/>
        <mobile>second mobile number</mobile>
        <email>second some@email.com</email>
      </contact>
    </contacts>
  </member>
</members>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:my="mynamespace" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="members|my:member">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>  
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node()[text()][ancestor::my:member]|@*[ancestor::my:member]">
    <xsl:variable name="vContact">
      <xsl:if test="ancestor-or-self::my:contact">
        <xsl:value-of select="count(ancestor-or-self::my:contact/preceding-sibling::my:contact) + 1"/>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}{$vContact}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<members>
   <member xmlns="mynamespace" id="1" status="1" url="someurl" date1="somedate"
           date2="someotherdate"
           description="some description"
           category="some category"
           contactId1="1"
           contactPerson1="some contact person"
           mobile1="mobile number"
           email1="some@email.com"
           contactId2="2"
           contactPerson2="second contact person"
           mobile2="second mobile number"
           email2="second some@email.com"/>
</members>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think dtb answer is the best way to do it. However, you have to note one important issue. Try to add another contact information and dtb code would crash. Because a member can have more than one contact information but yet can not have duplicate attributes. In order to work around that I updated the code to select only distinct attributes. To do that I implemented `IEqualityComparer<XAttribute>`. 
The updated linq expression would look like this

```
var result = new XDocument(new XElement(doc.Root.Name, 
                from x in doc.Root.Elements() 
                select new XElement(x.Name, (from y in x.Descendants() 
                                            where !y.HasElements
                                            select new XAttribute(y.Name.LocalName, y.Value)).Distinct(new XAttributeEqualityComparer())
                                            )));
```

As you can notice a Distinct call was added with a custom Equality comparer overload`(XAttributeEqualityComparer)`

```
    class XAttributeEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<XAttribute>
    {
        public bool Equals(XAttribute x, XAttribute y)
        {
            return x.Name == y.Name; 
        }

        public int GetHashCode(XAttribute obj)
        {
            return obj.Name.GetHashCode(); 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write an XSLT transform to convert the elements to attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this to create another XML document, or is just to make your processing simpler? If former is the case, then you just have to put all values in a map when you come across a leaf node and that's it. You can actually then iterate over the key-value pairs in the map to reconstruct an xml tag with just attributes.